# Where is the right place to create directories & call setResourceValue?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to create some directory and make it excluded from iCloud backup:

```
// create directory - someDir 
NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(someDir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

// set the directory to be excluded from iCloud backup
someDir.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
```

I am thinking to place the code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.swift`, is it correct?

Where is the right place to put the code (create directories & setResourceValue)?

Comment: If you don't want the file backed up and the file is replaceable, use the Caches folder.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking. Are you asking where to put the code to make the directory or where to create the directory itself?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, but my files are not replaceable.

Comment: @ryantxr where to put the code

Comment: If it's not replaceable, why don't you want it backed up?

Comment: @rmaddy I can't take the chance that iOS might clean it up although the data is dynamic. There are good reasons I don't want to use Cache folder & why `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` exists.

Answer (score 0):

If your app needs this directory when it runs, then you should put code to create it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Check to see if the directory already exists and if it does not exist, then create it.  I have done this in apps before and those apps have been running more than a year.

I would recommend making or using a separate class where you would put all the code details and just call if from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  That keeps the code in AppDelegate to a minimum.